# Dynamic batch insert SQL query with JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jooq

I am using JOOQ for SQL building in a dynamic way, as I prefer using the good old JDBCTemplate for execution and maintaining myself the domain objects instead of generating them with JOOQ. I have the following batch insert statement: `INSERT INTO my_table(field1, field2, ..., field20) values(<VALUES>);`

I would like to construct this SQL in a dynamic way. For constructing a select in this manner I have used SelectQuery and methods such as addOrderBy, addConditions, join, etc.

Is there any way to *add the column names* (i.e. field1, field2, ..., field20) to an InsertQuery? I would like to do something like this:

```
InsertQuery<Record> insertQuery = ctx.insertQuery(table("my_table"));
insertQuery.addColumns("field1", "field2", ..., "field20");
for (List<Object> values : valuesList) {
    insertQuery.addValues(values);
}
getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(insertQuery.getSQL(), insertQuery.getValues(), batchSize);
```

Comment: *"as I prefer using the good old JDBCTemplate for execution"* - Why?

Comment: Well, I do not want to rewrite my whole DAO layer, just want the more convenient SQL building, so I do not have to maintain that manually on each change.

Comment: I think you're overestimating the effort here. If you run a DML statement, both JdbcTemplate and jOOQ will provide you with an update count, except that if you go all in on jOOQ, you get *much* more out of it. But anyway, that wasn't the question here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```java
ctx.insertInto(table)
   .columns(columns)
   .valuesOfRows(valuesList.stream().collect(Rows.toRowList(...)))
   .execute();
```

Note that in jOOQ's terms, this is not a batch `INSERT` statement (multiple individual statements, single JDBC roundtrip), but a bulk `INSERT` statement (single individual statements with multiple rows). It corresponds to what you've attempted. If you prefer a `Batch` statement, then just create a dummy `INSERT` like this:

```java
ctx.insertInto(table)
   .columns(columns)
   .values(Collections.nCopies(n, null))
   .getSQL();
```

And extract its SQL. Since you're not about to execute the query with jOOQ, you don't need to pass all bind values to jOOQ, only to JdbcTemplate.

### Regarding the execution of jOOQ queries with JdbcTemplate

This isn't about your actual question, but I still like to mention it everywhere someone tries to execute a jOOQ query on JdbcTemplate, JDCB, JPA, etc. [You'll get *much* more out of jOOQ if you execute the queries with jOOQ, see this blog post I've written](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-execute-jooq-queries-with-jooq/).

Comment: I need the "multiple individual statements, single JDBC roundtrip", is there a way to get that?